# Access VBA - Looping through combobox records returns an empty (suspended) query in the SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, combobox

A while ago I migraited the Access backend for a project to an SQL server while keeping an Access frontend. I attached the tables doing Append TableDefs in Access  with the SQL server tables (creating linked tables). This all works fine.

This however had 1 problem, namely some queries (usually the bigger ones) getting the suspended state in the SQL server for very long. After some research I found out that the suspeneded state is getting removed if you loop through the recordset of the object which has the query.

For this I created several Init (global) functions that move to the last record and then back to the first record and by doing so removing the suspended state. This seems to work great but doing this for comboboxes I am getting weird 'empty' suspended queries in the SQL server. If I am not mistaken 'empty' suspended queries won't do much harm (they wont keep the 'filled' queries on hold). Though in a live environment you will see very very much 'empty' queries in the activity monitor and making it very confusing.

My public sub for stepping through the combobox it's recordset is as follow:

```
Public Sub InitComboBox(cmb As ComboBox)

    If cmb.RowSource <> "" Then
        ' Store initial value
        Dim initialIndex
        initialIndex = cmb.ListIndex


        ' Goto last item
        Dim lastRowIndex As Long
        lastRowIndex = cmb.ListCount - 1

        Dim lastComboRow
        lastComboRow = cmb.ItemData(lastRowIndex)
        ' Set value back to initial item
        lastComboRow = cmb.ItemData(initialIndex)
    End If

    cmb.GridlineThemeColorIndex = 1

End Sub
```

This function is called in the onload event of the form (it checks all the comboboxes on the form and loops through the recordsource of those comboboxes).

After some debugging I figured out that the following statement in the sub is causing an 'empty' query on the SQL server:

```
lastRowIndex = cmb.ListCount - 1
```

The question is, why is this specific line causing an 'empty' query with suspended state on my SQL server?

On my SQL server it looks like this by the way:
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. When I have a combobox with more rows than Access will load immediately, and "dropdown" the box, then I get a suspended query with ASYNC_NETOWRK_IO (not empty but with the combobox SQL). But once I call `cmb.ListCount`, the query disappears. Accessing `cmb.ListCount` forces Access to load all rows, which closes the query.

Comment: You are doing many unnecessary things in that function. Can you try changing it to `If cmb.RowSource <> "" Then lngDummy = cmb.ListCount` (nothing else) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Andre Changed the init function to your suggested `If cmb.RowSource <> "" Then lngDummy = cmb.ListCount` but this will cause a suspended query with data in it (so with the combobox SQL).

Comment: That's odd. In my SQL Server 2008 R2 the query goes away after `.ListCount` has run (has loaded all rows).

Comment: Weird, I'm testing it on a SQL Server 2012 (Express) by the way.